# Submit button hit the server when mandatory fields are empty

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In angular 7, I have just created one form with some fields and a Submit button. In the form, there are some mandatory fields. The problem is When I click on submit button, it get submitted when mandatory fields are empty.

I add the following code to the all input fields of my form in html.

```
<div class="error" *ngIf="form.get('TournamentEndDate').invalid && 
form.get('TournamentEndDate').touched">*This Field is Required</div>


<form name="createForm" #tourDetailsData='ngForm' 
(ngSubmit)="saveEmployee(tourDetails)" enctype='multipart/form-data' 
novalidate>
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
                    <label class="lable label-default">Tournament 
Name<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control" name='TournamentName' 
formControlName="TournamentName"
                        [(ngModel)]='tourDetails.TournamentName' required 
/>
                    <div class="error" 
*ngIf="form.get('TournamentName').invalid && 
form.get('TournamentName').touched">*This Field is Required</div>
                </div>
.....
.....
 <button type="submit" value="Submit" tooltip="Submit" >Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" value="Reset" tooltip="Reset" 
(click)="reset()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tourDetails.TournamentType = '';
    this.tourDetails.StarStatus = 0;
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      Logo: [null, [Validators.required]], TournamentType: [null, 
Validators.required],
      TournamentName: [null, Validators.required], TournamentStartDate: 
[null, [Validators.required]],
      ....
      ....
    });
  }
....
....
saveEmployee(tourDetailsData: Usermodel) {
if (this.form.valid) {
  console.log('form submitted');
} else {
   this.validateAllFormFields(this.form);
   }
  ....
  .....

validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
    const control = formGroup.get(field);
    if (control instanceof FormControl) {
       control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
       this.validateAllFormFields(control);
     }
  });
}
```

I expect the following result:

When I click submit button, it won't get submitted, when mandatory fields are empty. Once, all mandatory fields are entered, it get submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the button if the form is invalid:

```
 <button type="submit" value="Submit" tooltip="Submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use return in your code like this

```
    saveEmployee(tourDetailsData: Usermodel) {
if (this.form.valid) {
  console.log('form submitted');
} else {
   this.validateAllFormFields(this.form);
   }
  ...
  ...
  return;
 }

validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
    const control = formGroup.get(field);
    if (control instanceof FormControl) {
       control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
       this.validateAllFormFields(control);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the point of an empty return statement in the last line of a function? It'll return _undefined_ either way.

Comment: You put the `return` in the last line. There is no further code.

Comment: I have some API code after "return". If I put return in my code, next lines of codes are not executed. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do not disable the button if the form is not valid.
It's a very bad design practice.

What you can do is adding a condition on ng-submit on the validity of your form.

Here, your form `tourDetailsData` can be detected as valid or invalid thanks to `tourDetailsData.form.valid`.

Simply change `(ngSubmit)="saveEmployee(tourDetails)"` to `(ngSubmit)="tourDetailsData.form.valid && saveEmployee(tourDetails)"`

If the form is invalid, it won't trigger the saveEmployee method and it will show you the errors.

Comment: How to add this? If a I add this it shows error at console.

Comment: Sorry, edited, i typed without re-reading, tourDetailsData.form.valid has to be in the ngSubmit quotes